# How do I use JavaScript to change an image in my <section> by the press of a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website and a section of that website has a background image. I created a button and wrote some JS code to achieve this, however, it does not seem to be working. The button's id is 'mode' and the section's id is 'aboutSection'. I can't seem to find where the error is and I really hope it isn't just some typo (I've been looking over the code thoroughly).

Here is my JS code:

```
let imgArray = new Array();

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = 'sky1.jpg';

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = 'sky2.jpg';

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = 'sky3.jpg';

var i = 0;


document.querySelector('#mode').addEventListener('click', () =>{
    i = i < imgArray.length ? ++i : 0;
    document.querySelector('#aboutSection').style.backgroundImage = imgArray[i];
})
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Background images take a url:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_background.asp

```
document.querySelector('#aboutSection').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + imgArray[i].src + "')"
```

Though your array should be an array of strings/paths in this example.

Comment: Added ``.src`` inside the background-image url.